# Messenger in mobile APP

Tags: telerik, telerik-appbuilder, telerik-platform

I work on Telerik Framework, and using AppBuilder for creating mobile app

I need to add messenger component in mobile application, Is there any sample,plugin  for this request

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about push notifications? If so, there is a verified plugin for that: http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/pushnotification

Comment: Thanks for response, I need to add chatting in my mobile application , Is there any suggestion?

Comment: You can try a variety of technologies to do this. I wrote a tutorial on using SignalR to do something similar: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/real-time-reporting-with-signalr-kendo-ui-dataviz-and-icenium-part-1

Comment: Thanks again for response, I implement live chatting by using nodejs and socket.io , but I don't know how to add this code to my mobile app via AppBuilder .

Comment: Developing a hybrid (Cordova) app with AppBuilder is almost exactly the same as developing a SPA (single page application). So anything you do on the client side with JavaScript you can do with an AppBuilder app.